# MySQL - Select data from relational tables A, B, C, D, E if record was not found on Table F

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have 6 tables in my database: `users`, `courses`, `users_courses`, `lectures`, `users_lectures` and `attends`. In the headline, I referred to them as A, B, C, D, E and F.

I'm creating an attending system for lecture as a part of my school project and I need to run a query that selects only those lectures where users haven't yet attended.

`users` table holds information about user. Its' table structure is following:

```
id INT(10) USINGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(255)
email VARCHAR(255)
password VARCHAR(60)
created_at TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMESTAMP
```

`courses` table is a parent table for lectures that holds information about courses where lectures belongs to. Its' table structure is following:

```
id  INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(255)
created_at TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMESTAMP
```

`users_courses` is a relationship table between users and courses. It links users to courses. Its' table structure is following:

```
user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
course_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
```

`lectures` table holds information about upcoming lectures users are supposed to attend. It's table structure is following:

```
id INT(10)
starting_at DATETIME
ending_at DATETIME
course_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
created_at TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMESTAMP
```

`users_lectures` table is a relationship table between users and lectures. It links lectures to users. Its' table structure is following:

```
user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
lecture_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
```

`attends` table holds information about attending user's user's id, lecture's id and timestamps for created_at and updated_at. Its' table structure is following:

```
user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
lecture_id INT(10) UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY
created_at TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMESTAMP
```

**Question:**

Is it possible, with one query, to select only those upcoming lectures where users haven't yet attended?

Here's what I've tried, but it doesn't return any rows:

```
// PHP
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT
courses.name AS course,
lectures.id AS id,
lectures.starting_at,
lectures.ending_at,
users.name AS user_name,
users_lectures.user_id
FROM lectures
LEFT JOIN users_courses ON users_courses.course_id = lectures.course_id
LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = users_courses.course_id
LEFT JOIN users_lectures ON users_lectures.lecture_id = lectures.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = users_lectures.user_id
LEFT JOIN attends ON attends.lecture_id = users_lectures.lecture_id
WHERE users_lectures.user_id = :user_id
AND lectures.ending_at > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
AND lectures.ending_at > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
AND attends.lecture_id != users_lectures.lecture_id
AND attends.user_id != :user_id
ORDER BY lectures.starting_at DESC");
```

Am I missing something or thinking the whole structure in a wrong way?

Sorry for providing such a long text, but I wanted to be as specific as possible. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Filtering LEFT JOINed tables using a WHERE clause effectively turns them into INNER JOINs.  Try moving your restrictions to the ON clauses of the relevant tables.

Comment: To rephrase the question as I understand it: 

Find the lectures that belong to a course that a student has chosen (i.e. there is a record in student_courses that maps to the lectures table) where the student hasn't yet attended (i.e. there isn't a record in attends).

Comment: You understood it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to start with the subject of what you want to return. That would be users. So this will be your first table to select from (Note here: use AS to rename tables for brevity):

```
Select *
From users AS u
```

Next link together the data you want. Depending on how specific you want to be will depend on how many joins you will need to make (e.g. courseID vs CourseName).

Now assuming we want lots of human readable data such as names we will link the following tables.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_lectures AS ul ON u.id = ul.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN lectures AS l ON l.id = ul.lectureid
LEFT OUTER JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = l.courseid
LEFT OUTER JOIN attends AS a ON a.userid = u.id AND a.lectureid = l.id
```

And to top it off, to find people who didn't attend, they will not be in the attends table so we just check for people where the values are null for attends.

```
WHERE a.userid IS NULL
```

As a side note, you won't get any results with this in the WHERE clause

```
AND attends.lecture_id != users_lectures.lecture_id
```

Because you are joining with this statement

```
LEFT JOIN attends ON attends.lecture_id = users_lectures.lecture_id
```

Which contradict each other

Comment: Thank you sir :) The result was just like I wanted to be!